# Вконтакте "поделиться" для случая динамического контента

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

Добрый день всем форумчанам! Ситуация в следующем: есть яваскрипт-код для добавления на странице сайта кнопки вконтакте "поделиться". Если страниц несколько, с разными урлами, то при клике с каждой страницы по созданной кнопке получаются разные ссылки на разные страницы сайта в соц. сети. А если урл страниц один и тот же, а содержимое меняется динамически с помощью ajax по нажатию на внутренние ссылки страницы, то как получить ссылки в соц. сети на разный контент? Т.е. у меня для разного контента должны быть разные ссылки в соц. сети, а получается только одна ссылка на страницу с базовым урлом. Как быть? Сталкивался кто-нибудь с этим?

Answer (score 1):

Ну а кто мешает  с помощью java скрипта менять и урл для кнопок соцсетей? Или скрипт, который "приносить" контент, приносит и кнопку?

Comment: дело в том, что разный контент приноситься на элементы страницы, а урл при этом один на весь сайт и не меняется(

Comment: Но почему его нельзя менять динамически?

Comment: Реализовать это можно но нужно разбиратся со всеми API, легко и просто это делается только с FaceBook'oм...

Comment: да, с вконтактом будет сложно...